# Process memory examination

Tags: c, linux, gdb, shared

I have a process that listens on a socket for incoming connections.
When a connection arrives, a thread is created, the thread reads a request from the socket and sends back a reply. Here is the code of the process:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int fd, fd2, rc, *new_sock;
struct sockaddr_un serveraddr;
socklen_t peer_size;

/* Create the listening socket in SOCKET_PATH and listen to requests.
 * Each request gets a new thread
 */
fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d (%s) in socket()\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit (0);
}

memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(serveraddr.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH);

rc = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
if (rc < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "bind() failed - %d (%s)", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit (0);
}

rc = listen(fd, 50);
if (rc == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "listen() failed - %d (%s)", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit (0);
}

peer_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
while ((fd2 = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, &peer_size)) != -1) 
{
    pthread_t connection_thread;
    new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *new_sock = fd2;

    if(pthread_create(&connection_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create() failed - %d (%s)", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit (1);
    }
}

if (fd2 < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "accept() failed - %d (%s)", errno, strerror(errno));
}

exit (0);
}

static void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    unsigned char *response = malloc(2000);
    ...

    while((current_read_size = recv(sock , buf, sizeof(buf) , 0)) > 0) {
         // read request and write response
         // write()

    }
    free(response);    
    close(sock);
    free(socket_desc);
}
```

I also have a shared library that is writing to this socket, analyze the response and return data. Here is the code for it:

```
struct request {
    size_t payload_length;
    unsigned char payload[];
};

int request_fd;

Handle *mylib_init() 
{
request_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (request_fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d (%s) in socket()\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    return NULL;
}

memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(serveraddr.sun_path, DB_SOCKET_PATH);
if (connect(request_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d (%s) in connect()\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    goto err_close_request_fd;
}

...
}

int store(Handle *handle, size_t data_len, unsigned char *data)
{
    struct request *request;
    int read_len;

    if (request_fd > -1) {
        request = malloc(sizeof(struct request) + data_len);
        request->payload_length = data_len;
        if (data_len) {
            memcpy(request->payload, data, data_len);
        }

        if (write(request_fd, request, sizeof(struct request) + data_len) != (sizeof(struct request) + data_len)) {
            printf("Error %d (%s) in write()\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            free(request);
            return -1;
        }
        free(request);

        ...
         // Read response, analyze and return
        ... 
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I also have a small test executable that calls `store()` with bogus data. When I run the server application as daemon and the test executable in a loop, the server gets stuck after a short a while and is not doing anything, also not accepting new connections.

When running under gdb I see:

```
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 4526
Mapped address spaces:

Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
   0x10000    0x12000     0x2000        0x0 /opt/a.out
   0x21000    0x22000     0x1000     0x1000 /opt/a.out
   0x22000    0x43000    0x21000        0x0 [heap]
0xb5d00000 0xb5d01000     0x1000        0x0
0xb5d01000 0xb6500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xb6500000 0xb6521000    0x21000        0x0
0xb6521000 0xb6600000    0xdf000        0x0
0xb66b2000 0xb66b3000     0x1000        0x0
0xb6eb2000 0xb6f8d000    0xdb000        0x0 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so
0xb6f8d000 0xb6f9c000     0xf000    0xdb000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so
0xb6f9c000 0xb6f9e000     0x2000    0xda000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so
0xb6f9e000 0xb6f9f000     0x1000    0xdc000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so
0xb6f9f000 0xb6fa2000     0x3000        0x0
0xb6fa2000 0xb6fb2000    0x10000        0x0 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so
0xb6fb2000 0xb6fc1000     0xf000    0x10000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so
0xb6fc1000 0xb6fc2000     0x1000     0xf000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so
0xb6fc2000 0xb6fc3000     0x1000    0x10000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.19.so
0xb6fc3000 0xb6fc5000     0x2000        0x0
0xb6fd7000 0xb6fef000    0x18000        0x0 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so
0xb6ff6000 0xb6ffb000     0x5000        0x0
0xb6ffb000 0xb6ffc000     0x1000        0x0 [sigpage]
0xb6ffc000 0xb6ffd000     0x1000        0x0 [vvar]
0xb6ffd000 0xb6ffe000     0x1000        0x0 [vdso]
0xb6ffe000 0xb6fff000     0x1000    0x17000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so
0xb6fff000 0xb7000000     0x1000    0x18000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so
0xbefdf000 0xbf000000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
0xffff0000 0xffff1000     0x1000        0x0 [vectors]
```

Then when the program gets stuck it looks like:
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 4526
Mapped address spaces:

```
Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
   0x10000    0x12000     0x2000        0x0 /opt/a.out
   0x21000    0x22000     0x1000     0x1000 /opt/a.out
   0x22000    0x43000    0x21000        0x0 [heap]
0x96500000 0x96501000     0x1000        0x0
0x96501000 0x96d00000   0x7ff000        0x0 [stack:4899]
0x96d00000 0x96d01000     0x1000        0x0
0x96d01000 0x97500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x97500000 0x97501000     0x1000        0x0
0x97501000 0x97d00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x97d00000 0x97d01000     0x1000        0x0
0x97d01000 0x98500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x98500000 0x98501000     0x1000        0x0
0x98501000 0x98d00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x98d00000 0x98d01000     0x1000        0x0
0x98d01000 0x99500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x99500000 0x99501000     0x1000        0x0
0x99501000 0x99d00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x99d00000 0x99d01000     0x1000        0x0
0x99d01000 0x9a500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9a500000 0x9a501000     0x1000        0x0
0x9a501000 0x9ad00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9ad00000 0x9ad01000     0x1000        0x0
0x9ad01000 0x9b500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9b500000 0x9b501000     0x1000        0x0
0x9b501000 0x9bd00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9bd00000 0x9bd01000     0x1000        0x0
0x9bd01000 0x9c500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9c500000 0x9c501000     0x1000        0x0
0x9c501000 0x9cd00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9cd00000 0x9cd01000     0x1000        0x0
0x9cd01000 0x9d500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9d500000 0x9d501000     0x1000        0x0
0x9d501000 0x9dd00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9dd00000 0x9dd01000     0x1000        0x0
0x9dd01000 0x9e500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9e500000 0x9e501000     0x1000        0x0
0x9e501000 0x9ed00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9ed00000 0x9ed01000     0x1000        0x0
0x9ed01000 0x9f500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9f500000 0x9f501000     0x1000        0x0
0x9f501000 0x9fd00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0x9fd00000 0x9fd01000     0x1000        0x0
0x9fd01000 0xa0500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xa0500000 0xa0501000     0x1000        0x0
0xa0501000 0xa0d00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xa0d00000 0xa0d01000     0x1000        0x0
0xa0d01000 0xa1500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xa1500000 0xa1501000     0x1000        0x0
0xa1501000 0xa1d00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xa1d00000 0xa1d01000     0x1000        0x0
0xa1d01000 0xa2500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xa2500000 0xa2501000     0x1000        0x0
0xa2501000 0xa2d00000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xa2d00000 0xa2d01000     0x1000        0x0
/// ... MORE AND MORE OF THE SAME PATTERN ABOVE
0xb6fc3000 0xb6fc5000     0x2000        0x0
0xb6fd7000 0xb6fef000    0x18000        0x0 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so
0xb6ff6000 0xb6ffb000     0x5000        0x0
0xb6ffb000 0xb6ffc000     0x1000        0x0 [sigpage]
0xb6ffc000 0xb6ffd000     0x1000        0x0 [vvar]
0xb6ffd000 0xb6ffe000     0x1000        0x0 [vdso]
0xb6ffe000 0xb6fff000     0x1000    0x17000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so
0x9bd01000 0x9c500000   0x7ff000        0x0
0xb6fff000 0xb7000000     0x1000    0x18000 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.19.so
0xbefdf000 0xbf000000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
0xffff0000 0xffff1000     0x1000        0x0 [vectors]
```

What could be the cause of such program behavior? How can I debug the cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pthread_t` resources are not released. You should call `pthread_detach` or `pthread_join`, otherwise the `pthread_t` value remains valid consumes resources and I can guess that happens in this case.